# Get records based on count greater than 2 in postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table named user_activity.

| user_id | book_id | event_type_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |

event_type_id represents "User has viewed the book".

I want to write a Postgresql query to fetch book ids viewed more than twice by the user as below -

| user id | viewed book ids |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2 |

Comment: Please edit the question to show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: Not tested a quick thought: `select user_id, string_agg(book_id::text, ',') from user_activity group by user_id, book_id having count(*) > 2`. Using aggregate functions from here [Agg functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html).

Comment: *I want to write a Postgresql query*, okay why can't you? What is your question?

Comment: `string_agg()` gives you an array-looking `text`. Use `array_agg()` if you can help it: it looks pretty much the same, but lets you process it as an actual `array`, with subscripts, slices, functions, operators. Its elements also keep their original type and continue working with adequate functions and operators, plus ORMs can typically understand the array and map it adequately.

Comment: Have you tried anything???

Answer (score 2):

You have to `GROUP BY` twice - by `user_id, book_id` to extract the user-book pairs that qualify (the internal subquery) and then by `user_id` over the result.

```sql
SELECT user_id,
  STRING_AGG(book_id::text, ',') viewed_book_ids
FROM (
 SELECT user_id, book_id
 FROM user_activity
 WHERE event_type_id = 1
 GROUP BY user_id, book_id
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
) AS t
GROUP BY user_id;
```

[DB-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/md3XHMUwhzKkDPgsBpJZPM/0)
Unrelated, but what is `viewed_book_ids` going to be used for? Maybe it will be more useful as an array (use `array_agg` instead of `string_agg`) or a JSONB array (use `jsonb_agg`) rather than a comma-separated list text.